# SVN Syncing with Eclipse IDE 3.5.0

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I am currently using Eclipse 3.5.0 (Build id: 20090619-0625) with Subeclipse for SVN. I am looking for the feature that will update my local machine with the latest code that resides in the repository. I have seen the Team > Synchronise With Repository option, but i'm not sure if this will do what I want it to do.

I don't want to commit anything to the repository, I know how to do that no problem. I just want to update my local copy of the PHP project with what is on the server.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Picco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Team->Update

Comment: It appears as Team->Update to HEAD

Answer (score 1):

I know this could sound bad, but in my experience is safer to do not use subeclipse to commit or update.

I use subeclipse only for the icons, to remember me which files I modified. The I use Tortoise to commit or update my working copy.

Comment: The "diff" feature in Eclipse is pretty nice, so if you want to see *what* changes you made, it's good for that too. It draws little lines between the two versions, and such... But I had Subclipse do some weird stuff to my working copy once, so I agree with you. I do commits through Tortoise and then just go back to Eclipse and Refresh (F5) to see the pretty little gold cylinders.